# My own data to tensorflow MNIST pipeline gives ValueError: input elements number isn't divisible by 65536

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, mnist

I'm using my own data with [`tensorflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tags/tensorflow) [`MNIST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mnist) example pipeline but getting:

> ValueError: input has 16384 elements, which isn't divisible by 65536

I've been practicing with the example' data successfully. However, after introducing my own images which I resized to `128x128px` and generated ubytes idx files, I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "tensorimage.py", line 132, in 
>     train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 196, in minimize
>     grad_loss=grad_loss)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 253, in compute_gradients
>     colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 478, in gradients
>     in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py", line 298, in _ReshapeGrad
>     return [array_ops.reshape(grad, array_ops.shape(op.inputs[0])), None]
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1758, in reshape
>     name=name)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
>     op_def=op_def)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2319, in create_op
>     set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1711, in set_shapes_for_outputs
>     shapes = shape_func(op)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1867, in _ReshapeShape
>     (num_elements, known_elements))
> ValueError: input has 16384 elements, which isn't divisible by 65536
> ```

What's confusing to me is, I did indeed set the input to 16384 elements (128x128), however, I don't understand where 65536 came from. I combed through all of the code including the file `tensorflow/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py`
 but can't find where 65536 number came from.

Comment: (Edit) Here is how you could be more concise while asking (and format correctly). Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Thanks J. Chomel, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code exactly what's going wrong, but the summary is that TensorFlow thinks that the other dimensions of `input` result in a stride of 65536 elements, and so it's trying to infer the missing dimension by dividing the number of elements present by the known dimensions size, and spotting an error:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L1702

What happens if you print the size of `input` just before this error?

Comment: Thanks Pete! It looks like input

Comment: Thanks Pete. I printed out the enumerated new_shape variable generated in the for loop right above and it looks like the 65536 was generated by multiplying all the dimensions in new_shape (?, 32, 32, 64). 32x32x64=65536. It looks like the 64 value was generated in my 2nd convolution layer where I set 64 features for each 5x5 patch. So in order to match the 65536 tensor shape, I made my reshape from pooling layer into 32*32*64 which also equals 65536 instead of previously 16*16*64=16384. This got me on the next step so thanks for your help! I will probably ask more questions though but thanks!